# How would someone implement Modal navigation inside a tab navigation in Angular-Nativescript?

Tags: tabs, angular-ui-router, modal-dialog, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been struggling with the implementation of `Modal Navigation` inside `Tab Navigation` in `Nativescript`. So I wondered if someone had a good practice on how to implement what I am looking for.

I've tried multiple ways but none worked, I might lack some deep knowledge about `router navigation` since most error concerned `navigation`.

Here is a `playground` that tries to replicate what I am trying to achieve: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=VdmiR9&v=8

Errors that often occurred were:

1. `CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR Error: No componentRef found in DetachedRouteHandle`
2. `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FirstModalComponent -> ModalDialogParams]`

(While the `ModalDialogService` was injected inside the `AppModule`)

3. `No component factory found for RootModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents`

(While the `RootModalComponent` was added to the entryComponents of the lazy loaded module, so I added it to the AppModule)

4. `Can't resolve '~/app' in...`

(This error is weird because in some projects, the lazy loading of modules works with this import '~/app' while in other projects it fails)

5. `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/default'`

(This error occurred all the time, it seems I did not totally grasp the way of implementing routes)

If someone knows a way to do `modal navigation` inside `tab navigation`, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you have shared the right Playground sample, I don't find any modules or tab views in the code from the link.

Comment: @Manoj sorry, this is indeed the wrong playground, find the good one here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=VdmiR9&v=8

Comment: I think it's the issue with {N} Angular only while using outlets (frame) in TabViewItem and initiating modal dialog from there. You might try using simple components in TabView instead of outlets, that might at least make this no longer a blocker.

Comment: @Manoj would you have an example of TabViews with simple components? Thanks

Comment: Just refer the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view#basics).

Comment: @Manoj would it look like this? I am trying to combine both, this is why I leave the tabs routing. Find here v9 of playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=VdmiR9&v=9

Comment: Looks like problem is your are trying to navigate to another modal from one modal, comman practice is close existing modal and then navigate to another one.

Comment: @Narendra I tried something similar, basically I navigate back on closing the modal, and the I close the modal (programmatically). When doing so, navigation breaks...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, modal navigation inside a `tabview` is somewhat buggy in the `Nativescript Angular` framework, but there is a workaround. You can find a full implementation of this `modal navigation` inside this playground sample: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TkK7sQ&v=5

Fir further info, take a look at this issue I created on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1774